# Require Mutiple MFA on Keycloak at the same login

Tags: keycloak

I want to establish a Authentication flow in which multiple MFAs are required in order to login. Main goal is to protect the root account of master realm to enforce that two users must provide their token codes at the same login attempt so no one single user can gain super admin credentials in the tool.

Right now I found that the default authentication flows allow to use any of the MFAs provided, but haven't found a way that if there is, let's say 2 mfa are setup for the account, both of them need to be provided or a way to indicate a minimum number of different mfas to be used if there even more added.